Getting a list of OIDs for selected features in the WebMap interface using Python?
Could you suggest a method or function to retrieve a list of OIDs for the features selected from a service layer via the Select widget in a Web Map within Experience Builder? My goal is to use this list as input for the Download operation at a REST endpoint, triggered by a button press for downloading files.

AFAIK the closest you can get to this in the AGOL version of ExB is passing a single attribute to a parameter. There is no way to pass an array of all selected features through with the current configurations.
